# Like Functionality for Values in ListBox - VBA Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listbox, I am trying to select an Item inside it. Inorder to do that, I wrote this piece of code and it works,

```
With Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox
    .Values = "D2057898897"
End With
```

But I would like to have something like, `.Values Like "D20*"` But its giving me a syntax error.

Does Anyone know how to do this? Kindly share your thoughts !

Comment: The first sets the value the second is expected to be in an if and return True/False: `If .Values Like "D20*" then 'do something`

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve here, because your working code is an assignment and your broken syntax is a comparison.